# Design pattern for interface that determines order of method invocation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to create a Java interface with a number methods. But I want the user of the interface to only be able to invoke methods in the sequence or order that I define. For instance `buyTicket()` should not be called before `reserveTicket()`. **Q: Is there a design pattern or any tips on how to go about this?**

I considered:

- A)

  - Interface is wrapped, only showing the next possible method. Each invocation of a method returns a new `operation` that can be called after it, and so on.
  - So `ReserveTicketOperation` has `public BuyTicketOperation execute();`
  - Then `BuyTicketOperation` has `public RenderTicketOperation execute();`
- B)

  - Use some kind of `context` state machine that records the position of execution using enums and has a factory for obtaining the next operation.

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you guarantee that the order you define is _ALWAYS_ to be followed?  Also consider how to step backwards if needed.

Comment: Yes, the order must always be A -> B -> C -> D. If B fails, it can be retried or another method F can be called to clean up. (although clean up could maybe be handled inside B).

Comment: Then create an interface for each, which contains the next operation to be invoked (plus F to abort).  Not hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My immediate feeling: this is the **don't do it at all** pattern.

If the inner logic of your methods requires them to **always** call them in a certain order; then you are exposing an implementation detail that will make it very easy to use your interface to do something wrong.

Meaning: instead of trying to somehow force your "client code" to adhere to some specific order you should design your interfaces in a way that the client code doesn't need to care about "order".

In your particular example the problem seems to be that a ticket object can be "reserved" or "bought"; and of course, only "bought" tickets can be turned back, refunded, ...

In this case, the "solution" could be to have actually **different** classes for "reserved" tickets and "bought" tickets. Then you don't need to worry that somebody tries to refund a ticket that is only "reserved".

Comment: Very interesting. So `buyTicket` only accepts a `ReservedTicket (extends Ticket)` ? The reason i want to control flow is so that other developer using my classes don't need to know what order is necessary. Do you suggest controlling flow with differentiated paramaters / state on the inputs?

Comment: Subclassing can be one way to solve this. And btw: I didn't say that such a "re-design" is a simple task. All I am saying is: the approach that you have right now carries the implicit risk of an "easy to use wrong interface".

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Fluent Builder pattern.

One example of this is here.

http://blog.crisp.se/2013/10/09/perlundholm/another-builder-pattern-for-java

The idea is that you have an 'tree of allowable methods'. Each level of the tree is defined in one interface. So you have an 'order of interfaces'. All the methods in each interface do their job (which has to be void) and then returns another interface, corresponding to the next level of the tree.

Comment: I like that answer, but the problem is that if he is requiring dynamism, e.g. the ability to decide which method is next, the chaining of Builder will not work.

Comment: @Rob It could be adapted to allow flexibility. For example you may want to buy a ticket without reserving it first. All this means is that you make the first interface have two methods `ReserveTicket` and `BuyTicket` whose return types are different interfaces in the chain.

Comment: Of course, but then so could Template Method. What neither could handle is if it turns out some unanticipated path, e.g. A - C - E - B is chosen. That's all I am saying. I would argue AGAINST coding things that do that, I think it's fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, the answer to this one is simple: there is a pattern for this already amongst the 23 in the Gang of Four: [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

The whole idea is that you are codifying exactly what you are talking about a sequence of operations, but you are allowing each individual operation to be, in Meyer's terms 'open to extension.'

If you are not sure what those operations are until runtime, then TM will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), where your public interface defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in a public method, called template method, which defers some steps to private methods.

Or perhaps [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), where

> an object is used to represent and encapsulate all the information
>   needed to call a method at a later time. This information includes the
>   method name, the object that owns the method and values for the method
>   parameters.